# Downloading books sample iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I saw an iPhone application which had a download button to download books within the application itself. I want to know how to download books or something else from within an iPhone app.  Does anyone know of a tutorial or link about this?  Please help me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program you are referring to is most likely using an In App Purchase.  Apple describes this exact scenario in the In App Purchase documentation:

> For example, you could use In App Purchase to implement any of the following scenarios... A book reader application that allows the user to purchase and download new books.

You can read more about In App Purchases in Apple's [In App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267).  There are several third party guides floating around the web as well, if Apple's documentation is not sufficient.